# How to make a marker interface, or something similar

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a modal window service for my angular app, using the component factory resolver to load up dynamic content in the dialog box. Right now, I have it setup to allow any component to be passed into the modal window service, to be shown in the dialog box. The problem is, I only want components I "mark" to be allowed to thrown in the modal window service. So my initial thought went to an interface. But after a little research, it turns out that restricting it to an empty interface doesn't help at all because still any component can be passed in.

I only want "marked" components to be able to be passed in because these are the same components I will mark in my app module as [entry components](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).

Comment: Are you implementing that interface on the Components that you want to be sent as an argument? Also, have you set the type of the content to that of the interface?

Comment: What advantage would such a mark bring?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Yes, I'm implementing the interface on the components that I want to be sent as arguments, but since I have no properties to put in the interface, its just an empty interface, which has no restriction to it. And what you mean by your second question?

Comment: @JBNizet I would prohibit me from trying to pass a component, which wasn't an entry component, into the modal window service to be shown in the dialog box.

Comment: @R.Richards Doing a quick skim through of the article, is there a specific advanced type you think I could employ in this situation?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Because you could still add any not marked component to the entry components, and you could still forget to add a marked component to the entry components. So the mark really doesn't matter. What you need to do is document the fact that the components passed as argument must be added to the entry components as it's done by any dialog service: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component, https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-, https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dynamicdialog

Comment: I was thinking a Union Type, but without seeing any code, it is a bit of a guess.

Comment: If you have a fixed set of components you will accept, make a type union of all of them.  Or add a dummy property whose only purpose is to serve as a marker.  Possibly a private property of a class so you control who can extend it.  You should consider posting a [mcve] so the answers can be more concrete.

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of the techniques used to emulate [nominal types](https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/). They often use some kind of markers like:

```
const brand = Symbol();

interface Marker {
  [brand]: never;
}

interface Foo {
    content: string;
}

type Trusted = Marker & Foo;
```